# How to get rid of cat fur all over and around my room?

Tags: cats, grooming

I brush my cat with this thing:

[image]

I brush her every three days. My cat's fur is medium length (she's not long-haired; more like the cat in the picture).

Even with the brushing I still have cat hair everywhere in my room: on bedcovers, socks, and other clothes; and it's very hard to get rid of it!  I even don't know how to cleanup my bedcover right now, it's all covered in cat fur. I tried to wash it in the washing machine but this didn't help (and my cat likes to sleep on it).

What can I do to stop this fur apocalypse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cats shed. Most cats have fur of more than one color so they can visibly shed on anything.

Vacuuming, especially a vacuum that has a small beater-brush for upholstery, can help. Velour fur removers, sticky fur removers, or grooming gloves can all help.

[image: Velour lint brush]
<sup>Velour fur remover. The red cloth on the brush picks up fur from furniture or carpet.</sup>

[image: Sticky lint brush]
<sup>Sticky fur remover. Hair sticks to the scotch-tape-like surface.</sup>

[image: Pet grooming glove]
<sup>Pet grooming glove. The surface is similar to rubber and picks up hair when petting cat.</sup>

Keeping clothes in drawers and closets can help. Picking clothing that has colors and patterns that hide the fur can help more.

Personally, I gave up ages ago. Except for formal clothing, I simply accept that I will be wearing evidence that I have a cat, and if it bothers anyone that is **their** problem, not mine. The formal clothing gets stored in bags, checked for new fur before I go out, and bagged again immediately after dry-cleaning.

(People shed too, but we have hair rather than fur, and it behaves a bit differently.)

Comment: For rugs and upholstery, one thing I have found useful is to rub the fabric with a damp washcloth. The fur tends to ball up and can be removed more easily.

Comment: Also, when drying cat hair covered clothes in your dryer, use of anti-static sheets is essential. If you use them, the hair tends to go to the lint trap, but without them the hair just spreads evenly among everything in the load.